# If $D_1$ and $D_2$ are derivations of $A$, show that $D_1 ◦ D_2$ is not necessarily a derivation of $A$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $D_1$ and $D_2$ are derivations of $A$, show that $D_1 ◦ D_2$ is not necessarily a derivation of $A$.

What I worked out:

The Leibniz rule insists
$(D_1 ◦ D_2)(a) · b + a · (D_1 ◦ D_2)(b) = (D_1 ◦ D_2)(ab)$

$= D_1D_2(ab)$

= $D_1(D_2a)b + a(D_2b)$

= $D_1(D_2a)b+ D_1aD_2b$

= $(D_1 ◦ D_2)(a) · b + D_2aD_1b + D_1aD_1aD_2b + a · (D_1 ◦ D_2)(b)$,
which is true if and only if $D_1aD_2b = −D_2aD_1b$, which clearly isn’t necessarily the case.

Could someone give me a specific counterexample for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $A$ be the polynomial ring $k\left[X\right]$ over a field $k$. Let $D$ be the map $A \to A$ which sends every polynomial $p$ to its derivative.

(1) Show that $D$ is a derivation of $A$.

(2) What must $k$ satisfy in order for $D \circ D$ to be a derivation of $A$ ? (Most of the time it will not be, but sometimes it will be.)

Comment: $k$ must be $F_2$?

Comment: Almost. $k$ must have characteristic $2$.

Comment: Could you tell me why?

Comment: Just compute the second derivative of a polynomial over a characteristic-$2$ field and see what happens. And conversely, find a counterexample over a non-characteristic-$2$ ring (one choice of $f$ and $g$ that don't satisfy $\left(D \circ D\right) \left(fg\right) = \left(D \circ D\right) f \cdot g + f \cdot \left(D \circ D\right) g$ is enough here).